# How to trace the crash report?

Tags: ios, crash

Here is the stack trace of app. 
Note: App is in production and these logs are retrieved using Crash Organizer in xcode.

[image: Crash stack trace]
Any idea what is causing crash and how to trace or debug it?

Comment: In the crash information tab it is showing iOS 12.1 1% and iOS 12.0 99 %.

Comment: Have you enabled exception break point in project ?

Answer (score -1):

Add an Exception Breakpoint to your code, it can help you identify which line specifically is causing a crash.

Have a look at this post: [Exception Breakpoint in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode)

Comment: But it is production app stack trace. As per my knowledge i cannot add exception breakpoint for this.